# Split atoms into lists lisp

Tags: lisp

If I have an atom eg "a4" I need to be able to add 1 to the "4" part to make it a5, however since it is considered a string this is not possible, so if I could split (a4) into ((a)(4)) then I could do my calculations on the 4 then stick them back together again...

However, I am not sure how to split the atom into lists of the atom's word? Is this possible?

Edit: I am currently using common lisp. I have a list of string (a3 d14 c2) etc, but I need to be able to split each of them up, separating the starting letter and the number that proceeds it.

Comment: So what do you have? A string? A list? And what "Lisp" are you using? Common Lisp? Scheme? And what have you tried?

Comment: Common Lisp has string operations: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/c_sequen.htm

Comment: As stated, this is a _very_ unusual thing to do with LISP:  break a string into its parts (yes, you can use the char predicate), recognize some of those parts as forming a number like 14, convert that subsequence into an integer, add 1, then convert it back and add to the other parts.  Is that really what you're after here?  What's this meant to help with?  There may be a more LISP-like way to do that, whatever it is.

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.thefreedictionary.com/atom

> #### Atom
>
> [..] A part [..] considered to be an irreducible constituent of a specified system. [..]

I'd guess that this definition is what McCarthy has been thinking when he named Lisp's atoms.

Therefore, what you're trying to achieve is extremely uncommon and not how things generally work in (Common, or any) Lisp. Normally you represent data that is separate, such as your token and the number, as two different atoms and connect them e.g. using a cons cell:

```
(defvar *data* (cons "answer" 42))
*data*
;; => ("answer" . 42)
```

If you want this to be printed as `answer42`, well, then you have to print it:

```
(format t "~a~a" (car *data*) (cdr *data*))
```

The operation you wanted would then be something like this:

```
(defun inc-number (cell)
  "Please give me a better name and describe here what I do"
  (cons (car cell)
        (inc (cdr cell))))
```

That said, it is of course possible to achieve what you wanted:

Using [`string`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_string.htm) you can get the string representation of a symbol, with [`intern`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_intern.htm) you can (sort of) achieve the opposite. Inbetween you can manipulate the string as you like, including splitting it, converting it to a number, etc.

Comment: In Lisp the meaning of `atom` is `(not cons)`. This includes a lot of datatypes which can be taken apart... It's also very common to have symbol names which include numbers, counting up: dog1, dog2, dog3, ... The operation to take an atom apart has been traditionally called EXPLODE and the opposite is called IMPLODE. See the Lisp  FAQ: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/faqs/lang/lisp/part2/faq-doc-3.html

Comment: @RainerJoswig I know, though in a minimal Lisp a single data type (the symbol) would be enough, and as far as I know (please correct me if I'm wrong) the original (idea of) Lisp only had symbols. Thus a better name would be "self evaluating items" IMO. I see that there's danger of mixing up atoms and symbols in my answer, and I also guess that the OP actually meant symbols instead of atoms. I'll try to fix that. As for code that manipulates symbols: IMO this should only happen at the meta level, that is in some macro.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in MACLISP and INTERLISP. The function to convert a symbol in a list is called 'explode' in MACLISP and 'unpack' in INTERLISP; the function to convert a list in a symbol is called 'implode' in MACLISP, and 'pack' in INTERLISP. If your system has a GENSYM function -- a function to create symbols, as symbols are used as variables it is necessary for them to be created on the fly, specially in macro programming -- it may have functions similar to 'implode' and 'explode'.

If you are using common lisp, this google group discussion provides a implementation for 'implode' and 'explode': https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.lisp/SXhf78kCI7Q